# Elasticsearch to return documents based on 2 criteria where one is based on the other

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in the following format:

```
{
   "id": number
   "chefId: number
   "name": String,
   "ingredients": List<String>,
   "isSpecial": boolean
}
```

Here is a list of 5 documents:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "chefId": 1,
   "name": "Roasted Potatoes",
   "ingredients": ["Potato", "Onion", "Oil", "Salt"],
   "isSpecial": false
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "chefId": 1,
   "name": "Dauphinoise potatoes",
   "ingredients": ["Potato", "Garlic", "Cream", "Salt"],
   "isSpecial": true
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "chefId": 2,
   "name": "Boiled Potatoes",
   "ingredients": ["Potato", "Salt"],
   "isSpecial": true
},
{
   "id": 4,
   "chefId": 3
   "name": "Mashed Potatoes",
   "ingredients": ["Potato", "Butter", "Milk"],
   "isSpecial": false
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "chefId": 4
   "name": "Hash Browns",
   "ingredients": ["Potato", "Onion", "Egg"],
   "isSpecial": false
}
```

I will be doing a search where "Potatoes" is contained in the name field. Like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "status": {
        "value": "*Potatoes*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I also want to add some extra criteria when returning documents:

- If the ingredients contain onion or milk, then return the documents. So documents with the id 1 and 4 will be returned. Note that this means that we have documents returned where chef ids are 1 and 3.
- Then, for the documents where we haven't already got another document with the same chef id, return where the isSpecial flag is set to true. So only document 3 will be returned. 2 wouldn't be returned as we already have a document where the chef id is equal to one.

Is it possible to do this kind of chaining in Elasticsearch? I would like to be able to do this in a single query so that I can avoid adding logic to my (Java) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have that sort of logic in one elasticsearch query. You could have a tricky query with aggregations / post_filter and so to have all the data you need in one query and then transform it in your Java application.
But the best approach (and the more maintainable) is to have two queries.